# Swift api observable not working without wait

Tags: ios, swift, observable, combine

Hi I'm fetching data from a local api in a `LocationsDataService` class and assigning this as a `@Published var` in the data service and then using this in my `LocationsViewModel`. If I wait for my api request to complete, for example;

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
            let locations = dataService.locations
            self.locations = locations
        }
```

Then the locations are rendered on the screen.

This is my data service class;

```
//
//  LocationsDataService.swift
//  MapTest
//
//

import Foundation
import MapKit
import Combine

class LocationsDataService: ObservableObject {
    
    let token = "2|asOnUG27uCrcVuGxOO65kS25mX0nUSls5ApfemQy";
    @Published var locations: [Location] = []
    public var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    enum HTTPError: LocalizedError {
        case statusCode
    }
    
    init() {
        fetch()
    }
    
    func fetch() {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/api/locations") else {
            print("Invalid url...")
            return
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(
            url: url
        )
        urlRequest.setValue(
            "Bearer \(token)",
            forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization"
        )
        
        self.cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
                .tryMap { output in
                    guard let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                        throw HTTPError.statusCode
                    }
                    return output.data
                }
                .decode(type: [Location].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                    switch completion {
                    case .finished:
                        break
                    case .failure(let error):
                        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }, receiveValue: { locations in
                    self.locations = locations
                })
        
    }
    
}
```

And this is my view model

```
//
//  LocationsViewModel.swift
//  CoffeeShops
//
//

import Foundation
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

class LocationsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // all loaded locations
    @Published var locations: [Location]
    
   
    init() {
        let dataService = LocationsDataService() // the init function will do the api call
        
        self.locations = [Location(
            name: "Amsterdam",
            address: "Amsterdam",
            latitude: 52.3721009,
            longitude:  4.8912196,
            description: "Amsterdam",
            imageNames: [],
            link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseum")]
        

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
            let locations = dataService.locations
            self.locations = locations
            print(locations)
        }
        
    }
    

}
```

I'm not sure why I need to explicitly wait for the api before assigning it to the locations in the `LocationsViewModel` as the `LocationsDataService.locations` is `@Published var locations: [Location] = []`, therefore I thought it would be observed. Obviously it wouldn't be great to have to put in a time limit before I can update the screen as it could be done in 1 second or 5 seconds. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `@StateObject` is for use on a `View`. Remove it from your declaration inside `LocationsViewModel`. Not that nested `ObservableObject`s don't propagate state change notifications to their parent, so you'll need to call `objectWillChange.send()` manually if you want the parent to update.

Comment: Read my answer on your previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObservableObject` will make SwiftUI view to update the view when `@Published` changes. But when you're creating one `ObservableObject` inside an other one, there's no way it can automatically work.

You don't actually need `ObservableObject` for your service, you only need `@Published` for you property, and and there's how you can sync it with your view model:

```
private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

init() {
    cancellable = dataService.$locations.sink(receiveValue: { locations in
        self.locations = locations
    })
}
```